# Is there a way to add a button/link in a CSS "Content" tag?

Tags: html, css

I am making a screen size detector and want to make it where when your screen is too small, it alerts you with text saying "Your screen size is too small. Learn More."
Is there a way to do this?
My Code:

```
 /* Extra small devices*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {background: red;}
  .info{content: "Extra Small Screen";}
}

/* Small devices  */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  body {background: orange;}
}

/* Medium devices  */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {background: lightgray;}
} 

/* Large devices*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  body {background: lightgray;}
} 

/* Extra large device */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  body {background: lightgray;}
}
```

Comment: `media queries` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use html tags in `content`.

You could use an element that hides when width get above 600px.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  body { background: orange }
  .info { display: none }
}
```

Comment: but if he use `::after` a pseudo-element yes :)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to have an element that is hidden on displays that are large enough.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {background: red;}
  .info{ display: block} /* show the warning */
}
/* Small devices  */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  body {background: orange;}
  .info { display: none; } /* hide the warning */
}
/* etc for all the others */
```

and then have `.info` contain all the information/content/links you need to display.

Answer (score 0):

### you need a `::before` or `::after` in a html tag

in your case `.info` -> `.info::after` ...

### after this, now you can use `content: ;` css property

you can do some interesting things with `::after`

for example: [image]

```css
/* Extra small devices*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background: red;
    }
    .info::after {
        content: "Extra Small Screen";
    }
}


/* Small devices  */

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    body {
        background: orange;
    }
    .info::after {
        content: "Small";
    }
}


/* Medium devices  */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        background: lightgray;
    }
    .info::after {
        content: "Medium";
    }
}


/* Large devices*/

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    body {
        background: lightgray;
    }
    .info::after {
        content: "Large";
    }
}


/* Extra large device */

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    body {
        background: lightgray;
    }
    .info::after {
        content: "Extra large";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="info">your screen is: </div>
</body>


</html>
```